# Data on capacity shortages in the EC2 spot instance market

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In AWS, spot instances can be terminated for many reasons.  The classic cause of termination is that your bid price is exceeded by the market.  AWS has created useful historical graphs of spot instance prices for all instance types in all regions so that users can place appropriate bids.

However, recently I'm getting lots of spot instances terminated with the following message:

> instance-terminated-no-capacity: Your Spot instance was terminated because there is no Spot capacity available that matches your request

When deciding whether to use spot instances and which instance type to use, I'd like to know how often a instance class/type/region combination runs into capacity shortages.  Is there any way of getting timeseries stats on this, through an API or web console?  If not, does anyone have advice for avoiding this type of termination?

Comment: One unexpected observation: usually capacity shortages are not accompanied by a spike in the spot market price.  I would expect these two events to usually (but not always) accompany each other.  Can someone explain to me why they're not?

Comment: We are facing the same problem, we haven't managed to find anything useful in the AWS docs/internet. I believe that there is only one way to avoid losing instances is to use on-demand. Amazon does not seem to care about spot instance users that much.